# (ORACLE SQL) about subquery and operators like ALL,ANY etc

Tags: oracle, subquery, any

I have 3 Tables

```
CREATE TABLE airships( 
    idas number PRIMARY KEY, 
    nameas varchar2(20), 
    range number 
);

CREATE TABLE Certificate( 
    idem number NOT NULL, 
    idas number NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (idem) REFERENCES employees(idem), 
    FOREIGN KEY (idas) REFERENCES airships(idas) 
);

CREATE TABLE employees( 
    idem number PRIMARY KEY, 
    nameem varchar2(20), paycheck number 
);
```

I have to find idem for those employees who are certified for the biggest number of airships using a subquery and oparatos like EXISTS,IN,ALL,ANY

I've managed to find only one employee, whithout usig any of the oparatos.

```
Select  *
from (Select idem,count(idas) as AirshipName
      From Certificate
      Group By idem
      Order By count(idas) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Comment: Why do you have to use specific operators? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes. It's my homework

Comment: Doesn't that mean you should try to figure it out on your own, not get the Internet to do your homework for you? This is how you learn.

Comment: Yes, I should figure it out on my own, but this exercise it's taken from a bigger project that I have to present and I really cant't resolve it correctly .

Comment: I've tried to use max(count(idas)) But it doesen't work

Comment: You can't use two aggregate functions in the same expression. Use `COUNT(idas)` in the subquery, and `MAX(AirshipName)` in the outer query.

Comment: I stil don't get it.                                      'Select idem,MAX(AirshipName)
from (Select idem,count(idas) as AirshipName
      From Certificate
      Group By idem
      Order By count(idas) DESC)
Group By idem'                                                       returns all the values, not only the MAX ones.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do it using the specific operators you list. Here's how to do it with `HAVING`

The `ALL` operator is explained [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql.php). You can use this query:

```
SELECT "idem"
FROM Certificate
GROUP BY "idem"
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Certificate
    GROUP BY "idem")
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/315ea/6)

Comment: Replace `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(num_airships) ...)` with `HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT num_airships ...)`

Comment: @ypercube Thanks. My primary SQL expertise is with MySQL, I didn't know about this Oracle feature.

Comment: `ALL` is a standard SQL operator but rarely used by anyone - excpet perhaps textbooks and homeworks.

Comment: It nicely avoids having to write another level of subquery, though.

Comment: Yeah, true. In modern DBMS though, window functions would probably be more efficient for such a task.